# Identifier errors etc

Tags: xcode

Have a few errors in my code which I have commented out but don't know how to fix. Can you please take a look and tell me what I need to do to  fix it?

TIA

Implementation file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize textField;
@synthesize label;

@synthesize userName = _userName;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setTextField:nil];
    [self setLabel:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

    self.userName = self.textField.text;

    NSString *nameString = self.userName;
    if ([nameString length] == 0)
        nameString = @"World";
    }
NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", nameString]; // Use of undeclared identifier 'nameString'
self.label.text = greeting; // Unknown type 'self'
} // Expected external declaration
@end
```

Interface file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender;

@property (copy, nonatomic)NSString *userName;

@end
```

Comment: hint: look at the indention. And when you get an error that you can't find in the line with the error look at the previous line and if there is nothing wrong either go to the previous line again. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: OK, found the problem and got it fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last if block in the first file doesn't have an opening bracket

```
...
- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

    self.userName = self.textField.text;

    NSString *nameString = self.userName;
    if ([nameString length] == 0){
        nameString = @"World";
    }
    NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", nameString];
    self.label.text = greeting;
}
@end
```

Comment: Thank you. One more error I forgot to mention: At the top of the implementation file, I'm getting after @implementation ViewController I'm getting '@end is missing in implementation context' What does that mean?

Comment: That's because the previous error was hiding the @end at the end. Fixing the if block should fix that also